# How to send sms from php using the application smssync?

Tags: php, sms

I want to send sms from my website using my phone number in some time.
I'm trying Smssync ([this is URL of application's website](http://smssync.ushahidi.com/developers/)) but I din't know how to use it with php.
How can send sms from php using the Smssync app? Pleas help me.